# How to make deep link CoreSpotlight with Swiftui app Lifecycle?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm using this to add item on spotlight , and now i can search these item on spotlight

but how can i get to detail page when click the item on spotlight ?

I can not found a swiftui-app lifecycle sulotion

add item :

```
    let attributeSet = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet(itemContentType: kUTTypeContact as String)
    attributeSet.title = task
    attributeSet.contentDescription = task
    attributeSet.relatedUniqueIdentifier = uuid.uuidString
    attributeSet.identifier = uuid.uuidString
   
    attributeSet.addedDate = Date()

    let searchableItem = CSSearchableItem(uniqueIdentifier: uuid.uuidString, domainIdentifier: aType, attributeSet: attributeSet)

    CSSearchableIndex.default()
        .indexSearchableItems([searchableItem]) { error in
    
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error indexing: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("Indexed.")
                } // error
        } // .indexSearchableItems
```

my app.swift

```
import SwiftUI

import Intents
import CoreSpotlight
import CoreServices


let aType = "com.example.icecream-selection"

 

@main
struct DevoteApp: App {
    
    
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
    let nsUserActivity: NSUserActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: aType)
    
    @AppStorage("isDarkMode") var isDarkMode: Bool = false

    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    


    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            
             
             
            
             // CSSearchableItemActionType
            if nsUserActivity.activityType == CSSearchableItemActionType {


                if (nsUserActivity.userInfo?[CSSearchableItemActivityIdentifier] as? String) != nil {

                        let context = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext
                        let newItem = Item(context: context)
                        TodoDetail(item:newItem)


                    } // nil
            } else {
                
                ContentView()
                // IceContentView()
                    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
                    .preferredColorScheme(isDarkMode ? .dark : .light)
                    .onOpenURL { url in
                              print("Received URL: \(url)")
                            }
                    
                    .onContinueUserActivity( CSSearchableItemActionType) { userActivity in
                        if let color = userActivity.persistentIdentifier {
                                  print(">>>>>>>SUCCESS ACTIVITY<<<<<<<")
                                  print(color)
                              }
                            }
                    
             
             } // CSSearchableItemActionType
     
            
            
            
        }  // WindowGroup
        
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newScenePhase in
              switch newScenePhase {
              case .active:
                print("App is active")
                print("KEY TYPE")
                print(nsUserActivity.activityType)
                print(CSSearchableItemActionType)
                
                
                
              case .inactive:
                print("App is inactive")
              case .background:
                print("App is in background")
              @unknown default:
                print("Oh - interesting: I received an unexpected new value.")
              } // newScenePhase
            } // .onChange
        
    }  // Scene
}  // App
```

and how can i get the right item and goto TodoDetail() while user click the item out side ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: just give it up . swift ui is so hard to learn. life is short , i use flutter

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is to add this to one of your views that has a navigationLink with its viewModel containing the selectItem variable.

```
.onContinueUserActivity(CSSearchableItemActionType, perform: loadItem)

func loadItem(_ userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
    if let uniqueIdentifier = userActivity.userInfo?[CSSearchableItemActivityIdentifier] as? String {
        // You need to have a NavigationLink that you has the selection set to selectItem with it's tag being the uniqueIdentifier to trigger to navigation.
        viewModel.selectItem(with: uniqueIdentifier)
    }
}
```